# Docker Error When Compiling Tensorflow from source on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to build tensorflow from source on Raspberry PI using docker following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi

I have python 3.4 and 3.7 installed, and Docker version 18.06.3-ce. I get stuck on this step:

```
CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS="-e CI_BUILD_PYTHON=python3 -e CROSSTOOL_PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.4" \
tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI-PYTHON3 \
tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh
```

which at step 4 of the docker process fails:

```
...
Step 4/14 : RUN /install/install_bootstrap_deb_packages.sh
     ---> Running in d898ac94cbfe
    The command '/bin/sh -c /install/install_bootstrap_deb_packages.sh' returned a non-zero code: 139
    ERROR: docker build failed. Dockerfile is at /home/pi/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/Dockerfile.pi-python3
```

I am running raspian 8 (jessie) on a raspberry pi zero W. I have tried building multiple tensorflow versions, including the most stable release, and all have the same results. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

The guide you are following references *cross-compiling*, which means they are building on a host machine, while you are trying to build on the Pi.

To build Tensorflow go on raspberry pi you have to have **libtensorflow.so**, which is clibrary for Tensorflow used by GoLang.

Check out [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24144#issuecomment-445880533) post for more info on the issue you are having.

### Solution

If you wish to build Tensorflow on the Pi, follow [this guide](https://blog.meinside.pe.kr/TensorFlow-and-Go-on-Raspberry-Pi/) to walk you through building the required library, libtensorflow.so.

Comment: Sorry I might not have made myself entirely clear, I am looking to use tensorflow with python, and I am pretty sure this compiles it to be used with C. Unless I read it wrong?

Comment: `this guide` (https://blog.meinside.pe.kr/TensorFlow-and-Go-on-Raspberry-Pi/) link is dead